# 2 databases, one I can use over the LAN and one must be localhost, why?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have 2 database: harrington, which I created myself and pacsdb which I inherited. Both of these 2 are located in the same MySQL database. I am using Netbeans to debug things. In Netbeans I can connect to the database by

```
jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.100:3306/harrington?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull [fiji on Default schema]
jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.100:3306/pacsdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull [pacs on Default schema]
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pacsdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull [pacs on Default schema]
```

To my own database, harrington, I have no problems either in Netbeans or in my own Java program. Pacsdb will not connect using 192.168.0.100, but it will connect using localhost. In my program it gives

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'pacs'@'192.168.0.100' (using password: YES)
```

To check what is going on I queried the sql database table 'user'. I got that both users use '%' as Host which is what I would expect from the code

```
        sql = "create user 'pacs'@'%' identified by 'pacs'";
        OK1 = executeStatement(stm1, sql);
        if(OK1) {
            sql = "grant all on pacsdb.* to 'pacs'@'%' identified ";
            sql += "by 'pacs1' with grant option";
            executeStatement(stm1, sql);
            sql = "flush privileges";
            executeStatement(stm1, sql);
        }
```

I did find a difference when I queried the sql 'db' table. There I got 2 entries

```
Host      Db         User
%         harrington fiji
localhost pacsdb     pacs
```

I tried to delete the entry for pacsdb with localhost and insert a new entry for pacsdb with Host set to '%'. Apparently that isn't way to change from localhost, because I had difficulty to reach pacsdb. I deleted the entry from 'db' and inserted a new entry with '%' set back to 'localhost'. That got me back on line with the access denied error.

So my question is: how do I change from 'localhost' to '%'?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the query, but the connection to the database.

MySql has the possibility to limit the access from users accessing it from an IP different from localhost.

Probably you have not the right to access the database from your ip.

Try to add the correct right with the following command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'user'@'*'
IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

Obviously you can't connect remotely to do that command. You need to enter via SSH on the remote machine and launch that command locally.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and nothing changed. The syntax of your command is similar to what I was already using. I looked in the mysql user table and the same % appeared even with your syntax changed to '*'. Not that it is a big surprise.

Comment: After that I tried drop user 'pacs'. Now the user table showed only fiji without pacs, so that was good. Still the db table had no change with localhost pacsdb pacs, even though I had just killed pacs. You were of course correct that the error resulted not from a query but rather at the database connection stage. This was a bug which I fixed. It seems like the real problem is with that db entry with its use of localhost in place of %. Perhaps after the database is created it is impossible to change?